# How do I display child post types in the parent post type using custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called customer_care which uses a template called customer-care.php.

I have created a new customer_care called contact us and created a child of this called office address.

How do I get the permalink of office address children to display on the contact us (customer-care.php).

How show parent post and after child post and after click show content.

I am also use data-id & jquery.

I would greatly appreciate any help provided!

```html
//for display parent post

<?php
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 0, 'orderby' => 'menu_order' , 'post_type' => 'customer_care' );
      
 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  
 foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
 <li><a class="service-category-select" data-id="<?php echo strtolower($post->post_title);?>"><?php the_title() ?><span class="arrow"></span></a></li>   
 <?php
   endforeach; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
    
//for display child post

<!-- START: LOOP -->
<?php
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 0, 'post_type' => 'customer_care' );
      
 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  
      foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
 <nav class="sub-content ng-hide" data-id="<?php echo strtolower($post->post_title); ?>">
    <header class="title"><a class="service-list"><span class="arrow"></span><?php echo $post->post_title ?></a></header>
    <ul>
    
     <li>
      <a class="service-detail-selector" data-id="customer-care">Customer care <span class="arrow"></span></a>
     </li>
     
    </ul>
   </nav>
    <?php
      endforeach;  
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?> 
                <?php //endif; ?>
                <!-- END: LOOP -->
```

Comment: Ex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Comment: also try this..not work

Comment: please share your code

Comment: i am attach my code in my question

Comment: see demo link : https://www.etq-amsterdam.com/service-desk                           
same work this page

Comment: get the parent post id and add this.
because post_parent will be display all child post. post_parent is missing
 //for display child post: 
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 0, 'post_type' => 'customer_care','post_parent' => '2', );

Comment: so parent post id add in parent section(//for display parent post)....???

Comment: please suggest code .....for post_parent (edit my code)

Comment: please check another answer

Comment: Thanks but ...i am also this code try in earlier...not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this below code for children post

```
<?php
    $currentPostId = get_the_ID();
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'customer_care',
            'post_parent' => $currentPostId 
        );
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php } ?>


               <?php  echo get_the_title(); ?>

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for display parent post

<?php
     $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 0, 'orderby' => 'menu_order' , 'post_type' => 'customer_care' );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
 <li><a class="service-category-select" data-id="<?php echo strtolower($post->post_title);?>"><?php the_title() ?><span class="arrow"></span></a></li>   
    <?php
            endforeach; 
            wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

//for display child post

<!-- START: LOOP -->
<?php
    $currentPostId = get_the_ID();
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 0, 'post_type' => 'customer_care', 'post_parent' => $currentPostId );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

      foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
    <nav class="sub-content ng-hide" data-id="<?php echo strtolower($post->post_title); ?>">
                <header class="title"><a class="service-list"><span class="arrow"></span><?php echo $post->post_title ?></a></header>
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a class="service-detail-selector" data-id="customer-care">Customer care <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
```